# Download file using Amazon Android API

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was looking at the documentation of the Amazon to make a download of a file stored on the server. But the documentation is very poor

```
TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download(
  MY_BUCKET,     /* The bucket to download from */
  OBJECT_KEY,    /* The key for the object to download */
  MY_FILE        /* The file to download the object to */
);
```

How to find "The key for the object to download". It would not be a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [javadoc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/s3/transferutility/TransferUtility.html#download-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-):

- *key* - The key under which the object to download is stored.

From their [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html):

#### Object Keys

When you create an object, you specify the key name, which uniquely identifies the object in the bucket. For example, in the Amazon S3 console (see [AWS Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home)), when you highlight a bucket, a list of objects in your bucket appears. **These names are the object keys.** The name for a key is a sequence of Unicode characters whose UTF-8 encoding is at most 1024 bytes long.

Comment: Should this same blog comment http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html. Thanks for helping me